# Rails 3 make ajax using jquery and execute .js.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following haml code:

```
%input{:value => "", :type => "button",:class => "SendBtn", :onclick => "$.get('#{send_path}',{parameter:$('#parameter').val()}); "}
```

This input executes an event in the controller.

```
// This is my controller
def send

    if request.xhr?
        // do stuff
    end
end
```

But my js code in the corresponding .js.erb file is not being executed. It is returned as the response of the get request.

```
// send.js.erb
alert('hello');
```

How is the rails way to have this code executed?

Comment: it's not an answer to your question so I'll leave it as a comment: are you aware that you're using old techniches? 1) UJS: don't add events to html, attach them with JS. 2) don't use the ancient way `request.xhr?`, use `respond_to do |format| ...`. And 3) (not everyone would agree) don't send JS from an action, send JSON and let the JS code in the client manage it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not Rails related, it's jQuery. With the `get` method you are just fetching more or less plain text. This will not get executed. You could do an `eval` on the text but there is a better way. Use the [`getScript` method from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). This will fetch and execute your code.

As a side note, there are two things that are bothering me in your code:

1. You are using inline JavaScript. try to remove this by using a `data-` attribute for your send path, like this `data: { sendPath: send_path }`, and retrieving it with `$(yourInput).data('sendPath')` in your `application.js` file.
2. From my personal view I do not like to put executing JavaScript code in ERB templates. I find that this fragments the front end logic of my app. For me it worked better to put the logic in `.js` files and communicate with the server over JSON.

Comment: Another link that might help you: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Comment: I will try it. THanks for your answer. It is not my code =P , this is legacy code and I am trying to improve it.... thank you for your opinion.

Comment: For number 2.... I have read that it is a best practice for ajax requests... I don't really have logic in my js.erb, it just shows the error/success messages. What do you think about it?

Comment: Showing success and error messages is still some kind of logic that I would handle in JaveScript and a JSON response. I have a legacy project that uses extensively logic in rjs files that are scattered all over the place. I would not go down this route again.

Comment: I don't understand why having the logic in the a .js file is better than having a .js.erb for each action. Is it because I will have a lot of .js.erb with this option but on the other hand I will have a lot of events handled by the same .js? 
By the way, this project had LOTS of rjs and It was a nightmare.

Comment: Let's take your success/error example. You can easily abstract this logic, so you can use it in different actions (or your whole application) when doing it in JS. Your Rails app would just spit out success and error messages in a standardized way. Doing the same abstraction inside Rails could of course be done (e.g. with a view helper) but for me this violates the concept of unobtrusive JavaScript and the single responsibility principle. I don't think that it is the Rails view's responsibility to start interactions / animations in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As @topek said, you have to use `$.getScript`. Also in your situation better approach is to use `button_to` with `:remote => true` property instead of plain `input`.

```
<%= button_to "Do Something", 
              { :controller => :somecontroller, :action=> :something }, 
              { :remote => true } 
 %>
```

Also you can pass attributes to button_to (but you have add parameter to your route definition).

```
<%= button_to "Do Something",
         { :controller => :somecontroller, :action=> :something, :param => @object.id },
         { :remote => true } %>
```

Here goes documentation for `button_to`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: I will try it on a couple of days. Thanks.